# What am I doing wrong with my Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-3.5

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to use the asp.net regex.replace but it keeps replacing the wrong item.

I have 2 replaces. The first one does what I want it to it replaces what I want. The next replace that is almost a mirror image does not replace what I want.

So this is my sample code

```
<%@ Page Title="Tour" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <title>Website Portfolio Section - VisionWebCS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="B" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <!-- **START** -->
```

I am looking to replace both the meta tags.

```
<meta name=\"description\" content=\"A\" />
<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"B\" />
```

In my code first I replace the keywords meta tag with

```
<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"C\" />
```

This works  so my next task is to replace the description meta tag with this

```
<meta name=\"description\" content=\"D\" />
```

This does not work instead it replaces the "keywords" meta tag and then replaces the "description" tag.

Here is my test program so you all can try it out. Just through it in C# console app.

```
  private const string META_DESCRIPTION_REGEX = "<\\s* meta \\s* name=\"description\" \\s* content=\"(?<Description>.*)\" \\s* />";
        private const string META_KEYWORDS_REGEX = "<\\s* meta \\s* name=\"keywords\" \\s* content=\"(?<Keywords>.*)\" \\s* />";
        private static RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                                   | RegexOptions.Multiline
                                   | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
                                   | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                                   | RegexOptions.Compiled;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string text = "<%@ Page Title=\"Tour\" Language=\"C#\" MasterPageFile=\"~/Views/Shared/Site.Master\" Inherits=\"System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage\" %><asp:Content ID=\"Content1\" ContentPlaceHolderID=\"HeadContent\" runat=\"server\">    <title>Website Portfolio Section - VisionWebCS</title>    <meta name=\"description\" content=\"A\" />    <meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"B\" /></asp:Content><asp:Content ID=\"Content2\" ContentPlaceHolderID=\"MainContent\" runat=\"server\"><!-- **START** -->";
            Regex regex = new Regex(META_KEYWORDS_REGEX, regexOptions);
            string newKeywords = String.Format("<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"{0}\" />", "C");
            string output = regex.Replace(text, newKeywords);

            Regex regex2 = new Regex(META_DESCRIPTION_REGEX, regexOptions);
            string newDescription = String.Format("<meta name=\"description\" content=\"{0}\" />", "D");
            string newOutput = regex2.Replace(output, newDescription);
            Console.WriteLine(newOutput);
        }
```

This gets me a final output of

```
<%@ Page Title="Tour" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHold erID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <title>Website Portfolio Section - VisionW
        ebCS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="D" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Conten t ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <!-- **START**
    -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question without useless life lessons, you are having troubles because of greedy quantifiers. Try making them lazy by adding question marks:

```
<meta\\s+?name=\"description\"\\s+?content=\"(?<Description>.*?)\"\\s*?/>
```

Sure this regex won't work for all pages in the world, but if you need just make some quick replacement script for your own templates, regex is the fastest and easiest solution and the way to go.

Comment: Hmm that works but I don't get it. I thought even though I am using a greedy quantifiers it would keep going till it sees the "/>" and stop. So why does it go further? Like even when checking how many expressions this caught it always came back one.

Answer (score 7):

What are you doing wrong?  You are [parsing HTML with a regex](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)!

Recommended library for .NET: [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

Comment: So - what would you do instead, then?

Comment: @Will: +1 but you shoud provide a link/code snipet how to parse it with a proper parser

Comment: the graphic alone is funny enough to click

Comment: @marc_S my thoughts exactly. Just a quick glance at the article does not seem to show what to use instead. It also says in certain situations you can. I been able to parse html many times without a problem  and it was 100 times more complicated then what I doing right now.

Comment: You are highly encouraged to check out 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341%28VS.71%29.aspx 
http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp

Comment: Link to a parsing library added

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @serg555's answer - the issue is with the greedy quantifiers - making them lazy with '?' should solve the problem

```
<meta\\s*name=\"description\"\\s*content=\"(?<Description>.*?)\"\\s*/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn, love, and use the DOM. It is the W3C (HTML standards body) approved way to parse XML (HTML is a subset of XML) documents. Unless you have sufficient reason to believe your input HTML is horribly wrong, this is usually the best approach to start with.

[Learn here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp)

You are highly encouraged to check out 
[Walkthrough: Accessing the DHTML DOM from C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341%28VS.71%29.aspx)

You may also want to try jQuery, as it makes it very easy to search the DOM. [Like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036351/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-read-meta-tags).

Answer (score 0):

I needed description of URL in C# code and used [this site](https://regex101.com/)  to check my Regex code.

this is my final which work prefect:

```
      WebClient x = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
            string source = x.DownloadString(url);

            string description = Regex.Match(source, "<meta[^>]*name=[\"|\']description[\"|\'][^>]*content=[\"]([^\"]*)[\"][^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```