# How do I read all <meta..> from <head> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta-tags

In the page `<head>` I have `<script>`, `<style>`, `<link>` and `<meta>` tags. I just want to read meta information from the head and nothing else. I'm mainly interested in `<meta name="description"..>` and `<meta name="keywords"...>`.

I want the full meta tag and not its content. I know I can read content by doing

```
$('head meta[name=descritption]').attr('content')
```

but that's not what I want. I want an output like

```
<meta name="description" content="" >
<meta name="keywords" content="" >
```

What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036351/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-read-meta-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has no simple way of saying "get the HTML of the currently-selected element." Your meta tags probably have no content either, so you must want just the HTML of the meta tags. I'm not sure why you put the `[name=description]` condition there as it seems to contradict what you want, but you can keep it:

```
var html = '';
$("head meta").each(function () {
    html += $(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
});
alert(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName("meta");`

That'll do. And oh look, no jQuery necessary, since it's a simple tag selection.

But if jQuery is a must:

```
$("meta");
```

On a side-note, if you just wanted all meta tags, why did you do additional things?

Answer (score 0):

The following returns an array of all meta tags:

```
$('meta'); // [<meta name="description" content="">, etc, etc]
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('head meta')` gives you an array of jQuery objects, and you can use `.get(n)` to get the n-th as a regular [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) object. On this page:

```
$('head meta').get(0)
```

gives

```
<meta name="title" content="javascript - jQuery how do i read all &amp;lt;meta..&amp;gt; from &amp;lt;head&amp;gt; - Stack Overflow">
```