# java html scrape the facebook way

Tags: java, html, facebook, scrape

When you post a link to facebook, it shows a small thumbnail and a description of the content of that page.

I know it uses `og` meta tags in html pages, but sometimes even though these meta tags are not present, facebook manages somehow to get the thumbnail and the description

Example here : http://www.lepoint.fr/ (from `description` meta tag).

[image]

I know there are lots of good java html parsers, but is there an API that deals with all different meta tags to get the thumbnail and description of a given html page ?

Comment: ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036351/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-read-meta-tags

Answer (score 0):

not really a solution, but you could use embed.ly (http://embed.ly/), it does all the work and it has an api you can use to format the data the way you want it.