# How to get content of the meta tag of a webpage

Tags: html, tags, meta

I am trying to read the content of a meta tag of a secure web page. But finding it difficult as the properties are not the general one like name, author etc. If their is any way possible please tell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036351/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-read-meta-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you gone through these post in php.net ?

```
<meta name="author" content="name">
<meta name="keywords" content="php documentation">
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="a php manual">
<meta name="geo.position" content="49.33;-86.59">
</head> <!-- parsing stops here -->
```

read these meta tags using php code writte below

```
<?php
// Assuming the above tags are at www.example.com
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

// Notice how the keys are all lowercase now, and
// how . was replaced by _ in the key.
echo $tags['author'];       // name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
?>
```

these codes taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php