# How to get meta tags of current webpage using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I created following meta tags in head

```
<meta name="image" content="image url" />
<meta name="title" content="Page title" />
```

Now I used following code to extract URL and then the tags

```
$url='http://' .$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI'];
$tags = get_meta_tags($url); 
$image = $tags['image'];
$title = $tags['title'];
```

The page however keeps loading and outputs nothing.

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426232/how-to-get-content-of-the-meta-tag-of-a-webpage?rq=1

Comment: This isxactly the same code @Samir but it outputs nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like you call `get_meta_tags` script itself? If yes, you get infinite recursion and output nothing. Page keep loadings, and in the end, of course, would be a mistake - exceeded the maximum execution time.

Comment: My page is `domain.com/thispage.php` and I am calling it like `get_meta_tags(domain.com/thispage.php);` on the same page. So it is going in recursion is this what you meant?

Comment: If simple: When you first call the page in a browser script attempts to access itself and tries to read the meta tags. During this, he again calls itself again in order to read the meta tags. And so on to infinity. You can read that about recursion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science) | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect to see something if you're just assigning a variable and nothing else?

Do `var_dump($image)` and then for example `die()` to see it's content... or whatever you need.