# Jquery: If page has meta content- have css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to set up a div, visible only from pages with certain meta content
Here is the code. Picked up the first line somewhere. I'm a JQ noob, so pretty sure there is a mistake. But, for some reason, not much info on reading meta with jquery out there.

```
var m = $("meta[content=submenu]");    

$(".extramenulevel").css('display','block');
```

Comment: Have you tried: `if(m.length > 0){ $(".extramenulevel").css('display','block'); }`?

Comment: it's gonna work on all meta. i need only certain words

Comment: Ok, could you please add more information to the question about what meta content value you want to check for?

Comment: Also, HTML to give some idea of the structure we're working with. And: "*it's gonna work on all meta. [I] need only certain words*" - what does that even mean? Which words? Where are they? In an attribute, an attribute themself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use something like:

```
var author = $('meta[name=author]').attr("content");
```

(source: [Is it possible to use jQuery to read meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036351/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-read-meta-tags))

so you could do in your case something like:

```
if($('meta[content=submenu]').length>0)
    $(".extramenulevel").css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 2):

With little information to go on, and on the assumption that the `meta` content/element is not necessarily a child element of the element you're trying to style:

```
$(".extramenulevel").css('display', $('meta[content="submenu"]').length ? 'block' : 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var m = $("meta[content=submenu]");    
if($("ELEMENT").contains("$m")) {
  $(".extramenulevel").css('display','block'); // do stuff 
}
```

you just have to change ELEMENT with the html address of the object that if contains the variable m will attribute to .extramenulevel the css display: block