# Select value of property by using another property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this:

```
<meta prop="foo" name="randomname1">
<meta prop="bar" name="randomname2">
<meta prop="foobar" name="randomname3">
```

And I want to get the value of name property but only for prop="bar". Order of the tags might not be always the same, so indexes are not a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use jQuery to read meta tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036351/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-read-meta-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr()` to get something attribute from your html element

try this:

```
var a = $('meta[prop="bar"]').attr('name');
console.log(a);
// 'randomname2'
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
alert($('[prop=bar]').attr('name'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta prop="foo" name="randomname1">
<meta prop="bar" name="randomname2">
<meta prop="foobar" name="randomname3">
```

Use [attr selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.